# NSDateFormatter in IOS SWIFT 2

Tags: ios, swift

How can i achieve this kind of format?? using "NSDateFormatter"

March 1-2 2016?
Is there a format to get day only, Month only, Year only?

```
    let dateString = self.dateLists[indexPath.row]
    let dateFormatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let date2 = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(dateString as String)
```

Comment: please, refer below link it's working perfect... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35363650/4524276

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct dateformat to get everything you want from an Datestring.

If your date is a string, you need to convert it first to an NSDate()

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // the format of your string
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
 if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
   // conversation to NSDate() was successful
   // now convert to anything you want

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    let newDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
 }
```

Here are all available Dateformatters, for example:

Month only (as text):

```
“MMMM”
```

Or as 2 digit String:

```
“MM”
```

Here is all you need:

http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/

Comment: how can i convert string to NSDate.. all seems not working.. my format of saving of NSDate to String "MMMM dd YYYY hh:mm a"  then i need to convert it again to NSDate to get the month... i cant seem to get the Month only..

Comment: it has no sense to make NSDate instance with month only. month doesn't represent any time 'stamp'. there are infinite numbers of NSDate instances whit the same month ...

Answer (score 0):

```
let str1 = "May 12 1968 04:00 PM"
let str2 = "May"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str1) // nil
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str2) // May 1, 2000, 12:00 AM
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM dd yyyy hh:mm a"
let date3 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str1) // May 12, 1968, 04:00 PM
let date4 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str2) // nil
```

1. check your input string ... it must conform to you format
2. check your locale, even though you define your custom format, the
   system use the locale (gregorian vs julian calendar ... etc)
3. if it still doesn't work, parse you string 'manually'

Comment: May 30 2016 04:00 PM  this is my saved string.. i cant convert it back to NSDate..